# How not to show pasted hyperlinks as a hyperlinks?

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink

When I copy a hyperlink text such as a website address and paste it in MS Word, how can I just paste it as a plain text instead of a hyperlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the automatic recognition mentioned by @Dave:

1. Hit Space then Left Arrow to get before the space.
2. Hit Ctrl+Alt+V to Paste Special.
3. Select "Unformatted Text" and hit OK to paste.
4. Hit Right Arrow to move after the URL without triggering the automatic detection.

It's faster to do than to describe!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever any automatic formatting like this happens, just hit "Undo" (ctrl + z) and it will remove the automatic formatting that Word did.

This applies to hyperlinks, but it also applies to any other "automatic" fixes that Word does.

Answer (score 0):

You simply paste the link into Notepad first, then recopy and paste it into Word. This will ensure you are only pasting text.

However, Word will probably recognise it as a link and update it as such... If so, then after you paste in Word, right click on the link to bring up the context menu and click `Remove hyperlink`.

Lastly, because your question is actually unclear, the title says how not to show as hyperlink. You simply change the format of the text - remove the underline and change the colour to match the rest of your text.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a single hyperlink without losing the display text or image, right-click the hyperlink, and then click Remove Hyperlink.

[image]

To remove all hyperlinks in a document, press CTRL+A to select the entire document and then press CTRL+SHIFT+F9.

Note Performing this operation converts all fields, not just hyperlinks, to plain text.

[image]

more info:

[CLICK HERE!](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/delete-multiple-hyperlinks-microsoft-office-word/)

[OR HERE!](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291182)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off auto-hyperlinking in Word's options.

To turn off automatic hyperlinks, follow these steps (Microsoft Office Word 2010 and 2013):

1. On the *File* menu, click **Options**.
2. Click **Proofing**, and then click **AutoCorrect Options**.
3. On the *AutoFormat as you type* tab and (or) on the *AutoFormat* tab, click to clear the *Internet and network paths with hyperlinks* check box, and then click **OK**.
4. Click **OK** to close the *Word Options* dialog box.

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291182)